# Quais as principais diferenças entre VB.NET e C#?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, característica-linguagem

Além da sintaxe, quais as principais diferenças entre essas duas linguagens?

Existe alguma diferença de performance entre elas?

Ou existe algum caso em que é extremamente aconselhável usar uma linguagem e não a outra, ou VB.NET existe apenas para manter os programadores VB familiarizados com a nova linguagem?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Sua conclusão final é a melhor explicação para o VB.NET existir. Não vou achar nada facilmente, mas há algumas informações espalhadas que mostram que é isto. Ao contrário de algumas linguagens que são melhores em algum tipo de problema, quando se compara estas duas fica difícil apontar com clareza porque uma é melhor que outra se você não tiver um *background* anterior.

Nas versões atuais existem menos diferenças ainda e são quase integralmente intercambiáveis.

## Performance

Em termos de performance não há nada nas linguagens que mudam profundamente o resultado obtido, principalmente porque a maior parte do tempo será gasto na execução de funções que são a mesma coisa em ambas (quase sempre escritas em C# e transformadas em código CIL). Faz mais diferença a plataforma onde ela roda que a linguagem em si. Nem vou falar da questão de que algoritmos costumam dar mais diferença.

Claro que algumas características da linguagem podem eventualmente fazer uma pequena diferença, mas provavelmente você está comparando coisas diferentes. Então a comparação passa ser injusta. Para obter resultados iguais precisa escrever códigos diferentes. Mas note que a diferença será muito pequena e não dá para dizer claramente qual é mais vantajosa.

Em alguns casos o mesmo código pode produzir resultado melhor em uma do que a outra, mas com pouca modificação pode equiparar ambas ou até inverter o resultado. Comparar performance de linguagens é algo muito complicado, na prática não dá. Não existe linguagem mais rápida que a outra em termos gerais, principalmente quando elas possuem filosofias básicas tão semelhantes.

## Estilos

Não acho que uma lista das pequenas diferenças ajudaria definir alguma coisa relevante para escolher uma ou outra. O que é certo é que VB.NET tem um pouco menos cerimônia do que C#, mas muito pouco. Há mais conveniência em uma ou outra dependendo de como se olha o problema.

De uma maneira geral, os tipos, o gerenciamento de memória, quase todas as construções básicas de algoritmos e estrutura de dados funcionam iguais, a diferença é essencialmente sintática.

## Legado do VB

VB.NET pode usar um estilo um pouco mais próximo do VB original mas não é recomendado usá-lo em código novo. Pode parecer um pouco mais fácil usar esse estilo mas no fundo ele traz mais problemas no longo prazo. Como há esta recomendação, na prática a vantagem da familiaridade não é relevante.

É uma ilusão achar que você fará uma transição mais fácil do VB para o VB.NET. Código legado não se converte tão simplesmente e as diferenças do VB para o VB.NET são tão grandes que o trabalho de aprender VB.NET pode muito bem ser aproveitado para aprender C#. A sintaxe diferente entre as linguagens é a parte fácil do que tem que aprender.

## Diferença no suporte à linguagem

Há um pouco mais de exemplos e material disponível para C# do que VB.NET, mas nada significativo que faça muita diferença (isso tem mudado aos poucos e cada vez mais tem força no C# e não no VB.NET.

C# tem um *feeling* de ser a linguagem oficial e VB.NET está aí por causa do legado. Mas isto não se comprova se a análise for bem objetiva.

## Conclusão

Qualquer critério que pode ser observado parece ser subjetivo demais. Duvido que alguém consiga dar outro motivo para escolher uma ou outra a não ser gosto.

E recentemente a Microsoft deu demonstrações que não trabalhará mais no VB.NET. Ele continuará suportado, mas não não terá evolução. Isso é importante.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Mesmo o C# tendo este feeling de ser a oficial e o VB.Net o filho mal amado, o Query Syntax do LINQ no VB.Net é bem mais rico.

Comment: @TobyMosque Você poderia citar uma referência que mostre isto?

Comment: Esta informação está no Training Kit para a 70-516, se eu achar e for permitido, posso tirar uma foto da página em questão.

Comment: @TobyMosque Acho que citando a fonte e for apenas um trecho da obra cai no [uso justo](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use)

Comment: http://www.imgur.com/a/v1SfG eu investi a ordem da imagem, mas dá para ver que em VB.Net é possível utilizar take, skip, sum, max, etc com query syntax

Comment: Acabei de ver, voltando ao assunto, também li nestes livros de treinamento que os métodos em C# e Vb.Net possuem implementações diferentes dentro do Framework, então pode haver diferenças de desempenho entre executar o mesmo código em C# ou VB.Net

Comment: Mesmo código é relativo. É muito complicado comparar linguagens diferentes mas este assunto é muito extenso para discutirmos aqui. Muitas vezes o errado é justamente comparar o mesmo código. Linguagens diferentes pedem códigos diferentes.

Comment: Eu programava em VB desde o VB 4, quando aprendi a programar. E nunca tinha usado outra linguagem, exceto uma tempo que brinquei com Delphi. Mas mudei para C# pois me irritava alguns exemplos que não encontrava em VB e não conseguia transportar. @bigown disse "um pouco mais de exemplo em C#"... Eu acho (e fiz a transição por isso), que é mais que pouca diferença. É muito raro achar um exemplo em VB.NET que não aparece em C#, e comum achar um em C# que não trás o VB.

Answer (score 6):

## Além da sintaxe, quais as principais diferenças entre essas duas linguagens?

[Há um artigo no CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9978/Complete-Comparison-for-VB-NET-and-C) que ilustra extensivamente as diferenças. Não vale a pena comentar todas nesta resposta.

## Digo, existe alguma diferença de performance entre elas?

Não. As duas são primeiro compiladas em [CIL](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language), portanto a performance é idêntica.

## Ou existe algum caso em que é extremamente aconselhável usar uma linguagem e não a outra, ou VB.net existe apenas para manter os programadores VB familiarizados com a nova linguagem?

Acho que a resposta do @Maniero responde completamente a esta parte, com alguns adendos: a adaptação de programadores mais velhos é bastante custosa e muitos preferem não aprender uma nova linguagem.

Há, ainda, um outro agravante: A conversão de VB6 para VB.NET não é trivial, o que não traz benefício algum em se manter no VB.NET. Normalmente as aplicações precisam ser reescritas e as versões anteriores dos sistemas são abandonadas.

Answer (score 2):

> Ou existe algum caso em que é extremamente aconselhável usar uma
>   linguagem e não a outra?

Não é exatamente um caso que vou citar, é mais um conselho: cursos, tutoriais, exemplos, bibliotecas, trabalho, etc, na sua grande maioria (quase totalidade) estão/exigem **C#**.

Agora um conselho de que veio do VB6 e começou a aprender agora VB.net e C#, para quem tiver dúvida, foque no C# e não se arrependerá.

Para quem quiser começar:
[Curso Iniciando no C# - Inglês (com legenda)](http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/programa-o-no-jump-start-de-c-) Microsoft Virtual Academy

[Microsoft Virtual Academy](http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/) (se estiver pensando em pesquisar por VB.NET ou Visual Basic não clique aqui) ;)