# Para que serve e onde pode usar C#?

Tags: c#, android, ios, windows

Muitas pessoas falam bem demais de C#.

Qual a real funcionalidade dela hoje?

É serio que pode ser vinculada com JavaScript e CSS?

Ela serve para criar aplicações para Windows, Android e etc.?

Podem me dizer sobre ela e contar experiências, como utilizar e como aprender ela hoje? *Frameworks*?

Comment: Procure por cursos básicos de C# e .NET Core. Da pra criar Web Applications usando html, css, javascript como front end.
Da pra criar aplicações para Windows, aplicativos para celulares etc. Comece dos cursos bem básicos que encontrar. Pegue a apostila da escola Caelum no site deles (procure no Google). Bom resumindo, vale a pena. Apenas corra atrás e pesquise muito.

Comment: ook, muito obrigado. Uma outra pergunta o que é .NET?

Comment: **C# é uma baita linguagem.** Ela pode ser usada na web como **ASP NET MVC**, aí você consegue usa-la com HTML/JS. C# também é usada para aplicaçōes desktop e o melhor, hoje, pode ser usada para desenvolvimento **MOBILE** com **Xamarin**. ***É uma boa linguagem para aprender MVC, OO, entre outros.***

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 10):

Vou responder a parte que dá, que é o que fazemos aqui, opiniões servem pra nada a não ser influenciar indevidamente quem é ingênuo. Listar um monte de lugar pra aprender não vai ajudar. Mas pode ver isso [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23).

C# é uma linguagem como outra qualquer. Tem virtudes e defeitos como todas. Ela permite realizar virtualmente qualquer aplicação, salvo algumas imposições técnicas específicas. Claro que nem em todas é a melhor solução.

## Plataforma

Ela roda onde tiver um [CLR](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51281/101).

Ela não rodava em um navegador, mas agora roda com o advento do [WebAssembly](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/199158/101) (tem uma forma de tradução também, mas ainda não acho boa). Ela roda no lado do servidor gerando o que é necessário par o cliente.

O único banco de dados que ela roda diretamente dentro dele é o [SQL Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_CLR). Só não roda nos outros porque ninguém fez uma implementação. Note que não estou falando de se comunicar com outros bancos, tem bibliotecas para ela para se comunicar com todos que importam.

Ela roda nas três plataformas desktop que são usadas de fato e nas <strike>três</strike> duas maiores plataformas móveis. Além de rodar em outros sistemas poucos usados. Ainda roda em dispositivos embarcados e [IoT](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/203583/101), tais como TVs, e drones, ainda que isso ainda esteja no início. Se não roda em algum lugar é questão de alguém fazer uma implementação.

## Aplicações

Você pode fazer sistemas operacionais e *drivers* com alguma adaptação, mas não é o ideal.

Se deseja fazer uma aplicação *real time*, ela trará dificuldades, ainda que dê, mas *real time* mesmo (*hard*) qualquer linguagem sofre.

C# não é a linguagem mais otimizada do mundo, mas está longe de ser lenta, pelo contrário, ela se aproxima de C/C++ em muitas operações.

Ela não tem as melhores ferramentas estatísticas disponíveis, mas quebra um galho cima da média.

O código escala bem e possui bibliotecas virtualmente pra tudo o que pode precisar que importa. O que não existe é fácil fazer um *binding*.

Ela mantém a segurança de memória, tipos, etc. tão próximo quanto é possível.

Ela é relativamente fácil de escrever e dar manutenção nos códigos, poderosa e flexível, mas não atende bem necessidades extremas e de nichos muito específicos.

Enfim, pode fazer aplicações comercias, científicas, jogos, ela é de propósito geral.

## Conclusão

Na verdade quase tudo isso pode ser dito de várias linguagens.

Muitas pessoas falam bem demais, muitas falam mal demais. Na maior parte são opiniões sem base nos dois casos. Os que têm base podem ser tendenciosos. Se quer escolher bem aprenda profundamente todos conceitos fundamentais da computação para tomar a decisão certa. Se quer depender de pessoas aleatórias na internet manda ver no C# porque ela não tem grandes problemas que inviabilizem seu uso e parece que é o que deseja, isso é importante pra ajudar na decisão.

Se tiver perguntas mais específicas podemos ajudar mais.

Tem algumas coisas que podem ajudar, mas é o biquinho da ponta do *iceberg*:

- [Quais as diferenças mais relevantes entre C# e Java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/110142/101)
- [Quais as principais diferenças entre VB.NET e C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51599/101)
- [Qual a diferença entre "generics" (Java/C#) e "template" (C++)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/150181/101)
- [Quais as diferenças entre Tipos Genéricos em C# e em Java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/10032/101)
- [Java 8 "default method" versus C# "extend method"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/121240/101)
- [Existem vantagens objetivas em uma linguagem ser "case sensitive" ou não?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/74414/101)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).